# My egg is not hatching

Tags: pokemon-go

So I went out for a massive walk with my friend and I had a little while to walk before my 5km egg hatched like 0.5 more. So we were walking and 0.5 passed on my friends phone and my other egg though my one egg said 4.97km/5km. So I got home later on and it was still the same. I opened the game up the next day to find the egg was on 4.98km/5km so I thought it was broken or something, so I opened the app again a few hours after and it was like 4.98km still, it progressed to 4.99km/5km shortly after. Then I got fed up and closed the app. The next day (currently today) I have just opened my app back up and clicked onto my egg and it's saying 5km/5km and I've left it on for a while, and nothing's happened. I've tryed looking around the app for something and got nothing. I've even tried walking down the road, still nothing. Should I uninstall the app? Or any suggestions?

Comment: Did you have the app open while you went for your walk? It only counts if you do.

Comment: That happens to me sometimes, and usually around 4.98. But, the egg eventually hatches. Rebooting the app couldn't hurt.

Answer (score 1):

It is just a bug, if you walk around with the app open or just leave it open it will hatch sooner or later. I had the same problem and sometimes still do. After completing the egg distance it would happen randomly (sometimes instantly, sometimes after 5 min of extra walking).

Answer (score -1):

Thats a bug, you need to walk forever to hatch the egg.

Comment: Do you have any more information? Like a link to Niantic discussing this?

Comment: @twobugs you really taking his "walk forever" seriously?

Comment: This might sound crazy but I think it's possible Pokemon Go has a bug or two.